# If he left this morning he will be here tonight?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Sometimes it is very difficult for non-native speakers to understand 'if conditionals'.
The type 1 conditional is used to refer to the **present or future** where the situation is real (If + simple present simple future).

But what if the situation is **past and you don't know** whether it happend or not happened? For example, he said he would come today, but a big storm have come today, because of storm the phones do not working, so I don't know he left this morning or not, so in this situation what is correct?

a. If he left this morning he would be here tonight.
(This is conditional 2, but conditional 2 is not real, so I think this is not good.)

b. If he left this morning he will be here tonight.
(I think this is a little better, but what conditional type is this? Is this right in grammar?)

If these sentence are all wrong what is your suggestion (more natural expression)? What conditional type will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are speaking after he left, but before he arrived *(in the afternoon)*

> If he left this morning, he will be here tonight.

If you are speaking before he leaves in the morning *(very early)*

> If he leaves this morning, he will be here tonight.

If you are speaking after he left, and after he should have arrived *(very late)*

> If he left this morning, he would have been here tonight.
>   If he had left this morning, he would have been her tonight.